# nodejs port is insecure even though I am creating a secure server (https)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

this issue has been boggling my mind for days. There's nothing noticable to me that I have done, but my node port produces an insecure socket, while my site itself is completely secure (ssl). So mathtutortime.com is secure, but this is the error I get when I go to https://www.mathtutortime.com/account/get_tutoring/lobby.php:

[image]

[image]

I tried reinstalling my ssl certificate, as well as ensuring my ssl certificate isn't expired, but to no avail. I have also gone to the actual part of my site in node having this issue, and it indeed is not secure :( Even though mathtutortime.com IS.

Here's my code for lobby.php:

**gather data for site, then create a post request**

```
<script src="https://mathtutortime.com:3001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script>
var BACKEND_URL = 'https://mathtutortime.com:3001';
var SESH_END_INCORRECT = 'https://mathtutortime.com/account/get_tutoring/done_incorrect';
var SESH_END_CORRECT = 'https://mathtutortime.com/account/get_tutoring/done_correct';
var name = "<?php echo $_SESSION["username"]?>";
var pass = "<?php echo $_SESSION["password"]?>";
var time = 0;
var role = 'tutor';
$.post(`${BACKEND_URL}/requestWhiteboard`, { name, time, role, pass }, function(res){
window.location.href = `${BACKEND_URL}/whiteboards/${res.whiteboardId}`;


   </script>
```

And here's my server in node:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var all;
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./privatekey.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./certificate.crt'),
  requestCert: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};

const chat_port = 3001;

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app);
require('https').globalAgent.options.rejectUnauthorized = false;
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.post('/requestWhiteboard', function(req, res){
...
}

app.get('/socket.io.js', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/socket.io.js');
});


var host = '45.79.111.96';
server.listen(chat_port, host, function(){
    console.log('listening on *' + chat_port);
});
```

Also, socket.io.js is in my directory (referenced in an app.get below)

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: The certificate you're serving on port 3001 expired on 20/3/2020 - how is the certificate you read in nodejs "linked" to the one you get from letsencrypt?

Comment: You're right. Good find! How is it that the mathtutortime.com one (the only one I can see on the web host provider) is the one not expired yet on mathtutortime.com. How can I have two certificates on the same domain if I created a secure socket?

Comment: how is the file `./privatekey.key` and `./certificate.crt` related to the certificates that are stored by letsencrypt that are stored in `/etc/letsencrypt` on *nix systems? letsencrypt doesn't even create .crt or .key files - where did they come from?

Comment: disregard the last part of that comment - there's cert, chain, fullchain and privkey available for every domain

Comment: I feel like I'm so close, thanks for making me aware of that. I just don't have that /etc/letsencrypt. I think it might be somewhere else, but I see letsencrypt in cpanel. I just copied the key there that says doesn't expire for a few months into certificate.crt, but it's still not secure. PEM-Encoded Certificate is what I copied into certificate.crt, and I'm not sure where to put PEM-Encoded Issuer. I found my private key using cpanel though, still not working for some reason...

Comment: Whatever you've done has not changed the certificate - you say you have letsencrypt in cpanel - any way of finding where those files are? do you have root command line access to your server?